# How to create custom SOAP header values in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I need to make following custom SOAP HEADER in PHP for a soap request call.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
      <Username></Username>
      <Password></Password>
    </AuthHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ProductInfo xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
      <myXMLNode>xml</myXMLNode>
    </ProductInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For this, I have created following PHP code:

```
try {
    $soapHeader = new SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/', 'AuthHeader', ['Username' => '', 'Password' => '']);
    $soapClient = new SoapClient('http://192.168.1.1/examplewebservices/exampleweb.asmx?WSDL', ['cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'trace' => 1]);
    $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($soapHeader);
    $soapBody = [
        'ProductInfo' => [
            'xmlns' => 'http://www.example.com/',
            'myXMLNode' => [
                '_' => 'xml',
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $soapResponse = $soapClient->ProductInfo($soapBody);
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . $soapClient->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

But above generating this kind of XML, with ns1 as prefix, which I don't need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:AuthHeader>
            <ns1:Username></ns1:Username>
            <ns1:Password></ns1:Password>
        </ns1:AuthHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ProductInfo/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can anyone please help to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

U could use `SoapVar`. Try like:

```
//.... 
$authHeaders[] = '<Username>'.$auth['Username'].'</Username>';
$authHeaders[] = '<Password>'.$auth['Password'].'</Password>';
$autStr = implode('',$authHeaders);
$authSoapVar = new \SoapVar( $autStr, XSD_ANYXML, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
$headers = new \SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/','AuthHeader',$authSoapVar);
//...
```